# Kendo UI-Scheduler : How to create/Edit Multiple Events by customizing a kendo scheduler editor pop-up window

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-scheduler, telerik-scheduler

**How to create a custom template for kendo scheduler event editor pop-up for creating/editing a multiple events at a time using kendo scheduler.**
i already done the implementation of customized template for kendo scheduler editor,so any one please help me to solve this problem.